# WP8 (Windows Phone 8) - SDK

Tags: .net, html, windows-phone

One of my biggest issues with the WP7 was how limited the SDK was in certain areas. I can't change the volume, nor can I send text messages automatically (although I can with Android OS). So, if I wanted to make my phone turn to silent with no vibrate between 9pm and 7am Monday - Sunday... I can't.

If I wanted to schedule a text at a later date, I can't - all I can do is have the message populated, ready for me to send.

And why? It makes little sense to limit these. OK, it makes some sense in regards to stopping developers having access to sending text messages (to protect the consumer from malicious dudes (especially if there is a cost of the text involved))... but no! This is what internet security does - or the UAC in Windows... It allows users to set permissions. A program should try to send a text, the OS detect it and a new rule is created to always allow / deny (depending on user input) (with a  nice little remember my preference setting).

Any way, sorry for the rant but these 2 features are vital for the style of apps I've been asked to create. So, finally, my question: I know the SDK for WP8 is rumoured to be released late July 2012, but do we know if the limitation I mentioned above are to be lifted?

And my second question is, are any .NET developers running out to learn javscript because they feel that C# or VB.Net will suffer or go the same way as silverlight. I don't think it will but with so much marketing going on about HTML 5 I am interested to see if anyone is concerned about this.

Dave

Comment: Two heavily supported languages going the same way as a web framework? I'm not concerned. If I was concerned about change, I doubt I would have become a software developer.

Comment: I was at a win8 dev meeting at MS the other day, the marketting around HTML5 is just to look cool and open. 80+% of people will dev in C#/XAML.

Comment: @ Adam and @ Baboon.
Thank you both. It's nice to hear, especially since I've moved from web into software, I just had a horrible feeling I had made a horrible mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 8 SDK is available now:
https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk